# Is there a better way to send Image via P2P through internet than using CocoaAsyncSocket?

Tags: ios, p2p, peer

I'm a newbie developer especially in networking and I have read a lot and searched a lot about it but using [https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket](http://CocoaAsyncSocket) 
seems to me to be the only solution to send an image/Data through P2P through the internet between two iOS devices .... am I right? But its very complicated and I was wondering if there is a simpler library that could do the job? I appreciate any help.

Comment: which protocol do you want to implement when sending data between devices?

Comment: TCP @Raptor and thanks for caring

Comment: Do you think using this library is the best way to do it? @Raptor Most questions are about offline P2P. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use AirDrop (https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_airdrop_custom_data) or Push Notification (if the data size is not large) as well. Try to use existing feature of iOS.

Comment: @Raptor what i want is p2p over the internet.... Not offline